# Autocomplete minChars property

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am using jQuery autocomplete. Here is my
HTML

```
<input class="autocomplete_input">
```

JS

```
$(".autocomplete_input").autocomplete({
    source: autocompleteOptions
});

// autocompleteOptions is a array which contains all values for autocomplete
```

Everything is working fine. I want to dispaly all suggestions on `onFocus`. After some Googling and reading some similar questions on SO I found the `minChars` property of Autocomplete. I tried but still no luck

```
$(".autocomplete_input").autocomplete({
    source: autocompleteOptions,
    minChars:0
});
```

How can I use `minChars` correctly?

**EDIT1:**
I am using this [link](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions). Thank you Rory.
On given link I couldnt find `minLength` property.
**EDIT2:**
I tried

```
 $(".autocomplete_input").autocomplete({ minLength: 0, source: autocompleteOptions});
```

Still suggestions are not displayed on `onFocus`. One difference I noticed is if I type any char then corresponding results are displayed and if I delete that char using backslash then all suggestions are displayed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)?

The correct parameter would be `minLength`

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ minLength: 0, source: autocompleteOptions });
```

Comment: Yes I am using the same. How to define both `source` and `minChar/minLength` together ?

Comment: `.autocomplete({ minLength: 0 , source: "source here"});` as shown in my updated answer

Comment: I am using http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions. Here I can see `minChars`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions) is the plugin you're using, try this:

```
$(".autocomplete_input").autocomplete(
    autocompleteOptions,
    { minChars: 0 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for link. Yes I am using the same. I tried your suggestion but got error `Error: this.source is not a function
Source File: http://localhost:7009/portal/javascript/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js
Line: 322`

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
 * jQuery Autocomplete plugin 1.2.3
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Jörn Zaefferer
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 * With small modifications by Alfonso Gómez-Arzola.
 * See changelog for details.
 *
 */

in line 588 change this 

[[[ for (var i = q.length - 1; i >= options.minChars; i--) {   ]]]

for this 

[[[ for (var i = q.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {   ]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `focus` event and call autocomplete showing manually:

```
$(".autocomplete_input").autocomplete({
    source: autocompleteOptions
}).focus(
    function() {
        if (this.value == "") {
               $(this).autocomplete('search', '');
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks. I think easier option will be there. Or I will go for yours.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation page for jQuery autocomplete: 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

The option you're looking for is minLength

```
$(".autocomplete_input").autocomplete({
source: autocompleteOptions,
minLength:0
});
```

Answer (score 0):

set minchars: 0;
make below changes in your autocomplete.js file.

Inside "window.opera" add a click event like shown below

```
this.el.click(function () {
  e.onClick();
}),
```

and add this function after "onValueChange"

```
onClick: function () {
   var ae = this.getQuery(this.currentValue);
   if(ae.length < 1){
      this.onValueChange();
   }
},
```

look for "onValueChange" function and in there replace the return argument as shown below

```
//return (this.selectedIndex = -1), this.ignoreValueChange ? void (this.ignoreValueChange = !1) : void ("" === e || e.length < this.options.minChars ? this.hide() : this.getSuggestions(e));

return (this.selectedIndex = -1), this.ignoreValueChange ? void(this.ignoreValueChange = !1) : void (this.getSuggestions(e));
```